# Enter in MUC room with another username

Tags: ejabberd

When im trying to enter in a room with another username then i entered in room with a different username.
Like
my username is admin and when i send this xml to enter in room 
`<presence to="roomname@conference.server.com/fakeuser" type="available"/>`
then 'admin' will enter in room with 'fakename'
how to disallow this to all users so, they will enter in room with real names only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This patch blocks presence stanzas with nickname different than username, and returns an error to the user:

```
diff --git a/src/mod_muc_room.erl b/src/mod_muc_room.erl
index 492f9a4b3..3918401d1 100644
--- a/src/mod_muc_room.erl
+++ b/src/mod_muc_room.erl
@@ -342,6 +342,15 @@ normal_state({route, <<"">>, #iq{} = IQ}, StateData) ->
    true -> {stop, normal, StateData};
    false -> {next_state, normal_state, StateData}
     end;
+normal_state({route, Nick, #presence{from = From, lang = Lang} = Packet}, StateData)
+   when From#jid.luser /= Nick ->
+    ErrText = <<"It is not allowed to join the room with nickname different than username">>,
+    Err = xmpp:err_forbidden(ErrText, Lang),
+    ejabberd_router:route_error(Packet, Err),
+    case StateData#state.just_created of
+   true -> {stop, normal, StateData};
+   false -> {next_state, normal_state, StateData}
+    end;
 normal_state({route, Nick, #presence{from = From} = Packet}, StateData) ->
     Activity = get_user_activity(From, StateData),
     Now = p1_time_compat:system_time(micro_seconds),
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want occupants of a room to change their nickname. The rooms have an option to disallow "visitors" to change their nickname.

But maybe you also want to disallow "participants": there isn't any option for that, but it is possible to modify ejabberd source code, and recompile it, see the third patch that I provided in [Remove some options from room config MUC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52950985/remove-some-options-from-room-config-muc/52970333)

Comment: sorry bro. Im not talking about changing nickname. Its already disabled. Iam talking about entering in room with a different username. Please read the question again. Thanks for your reply bro.